# The union of two disjoint closed sets can't be an interval

Tags: calculus, general-topology, proof-verification

Let $F,G$ be subsets of $\mathbb{R}$, both closed and disjoint. Suppose their union is a closed interval. Then at least one of them is empty.

Well, I've got some doubts with my proofs(I wrote two of them), and I would be really grateful if you can check them:

**First**: Let $[c,d]$ be the interval(I'm assuming here that $F$ and $G$ are bounded, although this proof is generalizable if they aren't), and suppose $c \in F$. If there isn't any $x>c$ such that $[c,x] \subseteq F$ then $c$ is a cluster point of $G$ and hence belongs to $G$, which cannot be. Therefore there exists at least one interval $[c,x] \subseteq F$.* But $G$ can't be the complement of $[c,x]$, because $x$ would be a cluster point of $G$, which would imply $x$ in $G$. 
Therefore, there exists an open neighborhood to the right of $x$ which only has elements of F. The right endpoint of that neighborhood must belong to $F$ since is a cluster point of this set. Again $G$ cannot let this finish, cause such endpoint would be a cluster point of his too. Continuing like this, we will finally get that $[c,d]$ is indeed $F$ and $G$ is empty.

The problem in this proof is, I think, in the end. Some time ago, I saw the striking example that $\sum_{j=0}^{n}(\dfrac{1}{2})^j$ was less than two, for every $n$. So I don't see what prevents this to happen, since the mentioned neighborhoods are of a wholly arbitrary nature, and may be they never accomplish to cover $[c,d]$.

**Second**: This starts in the * of the previous proof. Let $A=\{x\in [c,d] ; [c,x] \subseteq  F\}$. As we saw, $A$ is not empty. Let $l$ be the supremum of A. I'll prove that $l$ belongs to A. Indeed, given a neighborhood to the left of l, there exists some $y$ in that neighborhood and in $F$ such that $[c,y]$ is in F. We see that $l$ is in the closure of $F$, and thus in $F$ and not in $G$. Hence exists a neighborhood of l not containing any point of G. For this to be possible, it must be $l=d$, or l woudn't be the supremum. Using the definition of supremum with that neighborhood, we finally get that $[c,d] \subseteq F$.

I trust more in the second than in the first, but I'd like to know anyway if the first was really wrong. Besides that, there is another way of proving this?

Comment: This is nearly trivial assuming a standard definition of connectivity. What definition of connectness are you using?

Comment: Any, I didn't know what connectivity was until now.

Comment: OK, so this is a pre-connectivity exercise.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there another way of proving this?

Suppose $F$ is non-empty. It is bounded above by $d$, so it has a supremum $x$. Then $x \in F$, because $F$ is closed. And if $x < d$, then $(x,d] \subseteq G$, so $x \in G$, because $G$ is closed. But this contradicts $F \cap G = \emptyset$. Therefore $x = d$, which means $d \in F$.

Similarly, if $G$ is non-empty, then $d \in G$, which also contradicts $F \cap G = \emptyset$. Hence either $F$ or $G$ is empty.

I think this is simpler than both your proofs, but you were on the way there! If you had written three proofs, this would have been your third.